# C static initializer element is not constant error

Tags: c, static

this is my source code in C language
i want to definition basic data using static, out side the function

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char * URI;
    char * file;
} redirect_t;

typedef struct {
    char * URI;
    char * file;
    long long content_length;
} content_t;

typedef struct {
    content_t contents[10];
    redirect_t redirects[10];
} host_t;

typedef struct {
    unsigned max_requests;
    host_t hosts[10];
} addr_t;

static addr_t addr_list[] = {
        (addr_t) { 24,
            {
                (host_t) {
                    {
                        (content_t) { "URI" },
                        (content_t) { "URI2" },
                        (content_t) { "URI3" },
                    },
                    {
                        (redirect_t) { "URI5" },
                        (redirect_t) { "URI6" },
                        (redirect_t) { "URI7" },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
};

int main() {


    return 0;
}
```

**but i got (initializer element is not constant) error**

and this is my compile result

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\C Projects\untitled\main.c:27:26: error: initializer element is not constant
                 (host_t) {
                          ^
C:\Users\x\Documents\C Projects\untitled\main.c:27:26: note: (near initialization for '(anonymous).hosts')
C:\Users\x\Documents\C Projects\untitled\main.c:25:18: error: initializer element is not constant
         (addr_t) { 24,
                  ^
C:\Users\x\Documents\C Projects\untitled\main.c:25:18: note: (near initialization for 'addr_list')
C:\Users\x\Documents\C Projects\untitled\main.c:25:9: error: initializer element is not constant
```

i know that i can use `malloc` inside a function and insert the data into the (addr_list) but i want to insert it directly without any dynamic allocation. what is the problem? why i get error like this !

Comment: Compiles for me in clang, but not gcc.  Edit: Seems GCC doesn't like you casting the elements of your struct.  Get rid of the casts and I believe it will compile.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons What you call casts looks like _compound literals_.

Comment: @chux Ah, I see.  I find it curious that those aren't considered constants especially at file scope (at least not by the standard or I'd expect gcc to conform).

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Likely for the same syntactical reason `int xx = 5;
int yy = xx;` leads to "error: initializer element is not constant" for `yy`.

Comment: @chux I suppose so.  I was initially thinking of them as being constant, but the fact that you can get a pointer to them and then alter the contents does mean they are not in fact constant.  Of course if you try to use them as the OP did, then it means you dont' have a pointer and cannot change it, which may be the reason clang decided to support doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using compound literals in this way is non-standard, they are not considered "constants" but objects. The right tool are designated  initializers. E.g for your type `host_t` an initializer would look like

```
                {
                    .contents  = { .URI = "URI",  },
                    .redirects = { .URI = "URI5", },
                },
```

Comment: can you give me the full example with 3 contents like my program?